# Avoiding empty string values on request object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

For a certain axios request:

```
            API.post(
              `v${process.env.REACT_APP_API_VERSION}/register/company/`,
              {
                type: values.type,
                dba: values.dba,
                ein: values.ein,
                file_type: values.file_type,
              },
```

I'd like to avoid sending parameters if they're not assigned a value (are still "").

i.e. I would like to know the cleanest way of only including non-empty parameters in my request object. 
I can do this using an if check but doing so for every item on larger requests wouldn't make sense.
for example:

```
            const postData = {
              first_name: values.first_name,
              last_name: values.last_name
            };
            if (values.middle_name !== "") {
              postData.middle_name = values.middle_name;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: How about `Object.entries(values).reduce((acc,  [k,v] ) => { if(!!v) { acc[k] = v; } return acc })`

Comment: Another option is using the spread operator:

```const postData = {
   ...(condition) && {someprop: propvalue},
   first_name: values.first_name
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
  if(!values[key]) delete values[key];
})
```

What it basically does is it deletes any element inside the `values` object that is falsey, which includes empty strings.

Comment: `TypeError: postData.keys is not a function`

Comment: Oh. YOu dont replace `Object` with your Object's name. You should replace `values` instead. Like so: `Object.keys(postData).map...`

Comment: Works fine but I just have a warning, perhaps I should just add a return null?

Comment: `Line 78:43:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return`

Comment: @OmarHussein Use `.forEach(..)` instead of `.map(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution I can think of. For general solution I'd use a wrapper, but if you need to check only few of properties, this one can be enough.

```
        const v = values; 
        API.post(
          `v${process.env.REACT_APP_API_VERSION}/register/company/`,
          {
            ...(v.type&&{type: v.type}),
            ...(v.dba&&{dba: v.dba}),
            ...(v.ein&&{type: v.ein}),
            file_type: values.file_type,
          },
```